# Different Tailwind behaviour on different ports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, tailwind-css

I played a little with Tailwind and it is so good. I worked on default settings project with vue cli. I make configurations, and on port 8080 everything works fine. My config rules which looks like that:

```
...
secondary: 'var(--color-bg-secondary)',
...
```

after serve are rendered as:

```
.bg-secondary {
  background-color: var(--color-bg-secondary);
}
```

which is perfect for me.

But when I change port on another than 8080 by editing vue.config:

```
devServer: { port: 8081 },
```

rules are translated on color:

```
.bg-secondary {
   background-color: rgb(192, 134, 27);
}
```

and added again to page. It seems on different port tahn 8080 postCss works twice? But the second one is incorrect?

Why is that hapend?

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8080, //only with this port works properly
    open: true
  },
  lintOnSave: true
};
```

.

```
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.vue',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      textColor:{
        default: {
          '1': 'var(--color-default-1)',
          ...
        },
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        ...
      },
      backgroundColor: {
        primary: 'var(--color-bg-primary)',
        ...
        color: {
          primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
          ..
        }
      },
      borderColor: {
          primary: 'var(--color-border-primary)',
          ...
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

and no webpack config different than default generated by vue-cli ("@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",)

Comment: Could you provide the config files of vue and webpack?

Comment: added to question